# Django POST dict empty despite form

Tags: django, post, heroku, dictionary

Django 1.4.1. I have a form which appears to have all proper values present in the html yet the POST dict appears empty.

views.py (relevant portion):

```
@login_required
def event(request, event_id):

    event = Event.objects.get(pk=event_id)
    crew = event.userprofile_set.all()
    current_user = request.user.get_profile()
    if current_user in crew:
         current_user_is_not_crew = False
    elif request.user == event.host:
         current_user_is_not_crew = False    
    else:
         current_user_is_not_crew = True
    if event.date > datetime.now():
        future_event = True
    else:
        future_event = False
    context = RequestContext(request)
    context['event'] = event
    context['crew'] = crew
    context['current_user_is_not_crew'] = current_user_is_not_crew
    context['future_event'] = future_event
    return render_to_response('event.html', context)



def commit(request):
    """
    Commit user to event. Check if enough members
    (2 including event creator) are taking part to
    publish the event. If there are, mark
    sufficient_participants Boolean and publish the
    event to Facebook.

    clashing_commitment checks that request user is not
    already committed to an event on this day. If she is
    they will not be allowed to commit to this.
    """
    member = request.user.get_profile()
    event_id = request.POST.get('event_id','')
    print event_id
    event = Event.objects.get(pk=event_id)
    event_less_3_hours = event.date - timedelta(hours=3)
    event_plus_3_hours = event.date + timedelta(hours=3)
    clashing_commitment = Event.objects.filter(userprofile__exact=member).\
        filter(date__range=(event_less_3_hours, event_plus_3_hours))    
    crew = event.userprofile_set.all()
    print crew
    context = RequestContext(request)
    if clashing_commitment:
        context['event'] = event
        context['crew'] = crew
        messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 
            'You are already committed to another event at this time. \
            You cannot commit to two simultaneous events. Sorry! \
            <a href="mailto:me@gmail.com">Ask admin</a> to remove you from other event if necessary.')
        return render_to_response('event.html', context)


    try:
        # cronix test page token:
        graph = GraphAPI("CAAk6zW7VBJL9eUZD")
        # Publish Facebook event on page
        eventdate = event.date
        date_iso = eventdate.isoformat()
        date_iso += '+0100'
        graph.post(
            path = '/449/events',
            retry=1,
            name = event.name,
            description = event.description,
            location = event.location,
            start_time = date_iso,
            )
        # To post event image, retrieve all Page events and identify current event
        # by its precise date in ISO format as captured above.
        # TODO This is a hacky, error-prone means of identifying
        # events and needs to be fixed.
        fb_events = graph.get('/449/events')
        fb_events = fb_events['data']
        for item in fb_events:
            if item["start_time"] == date_iso:
                fb_event = item
        fb_event_id = fb_event.values()[0]
        fb_event_path = fb_event_id + '/picture'
        # Get appropriate, environment-specific root url for urllib call below.
        # TODO Set two img_url variables and wrap urllib2.urlopen call
        # in try/except as it is error prone
        try:
            if os.environ['ENV'] == 'staging':
                img_url = 'http://www.mysite.org.uk//img/logo-fb.jpg'
        except:
            img_url = 'http://localhost:8000/static/img/logo.png'
        print img_url
        graph.post(
            path = fb_event_path,
            source = urllib2.urlopen(img_url))


    except GraphAPI.OAuthError, e:
        print e.message
        return redirect('commit')
    member.event_commitments.add(event)
    crew = event.userprofile_set.all()
    if crew.count() > settings.EVENT_PUB_COMMITTED_CRITICAL_MASS and event.sufficient_participants == 0:
        event.sufficient_participants = 1
        event.save()
        publish_event = True
    context['event'] = event
    context['crew'] = crew
    messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'You have committed to this event.')
    return render_to_response('event.html', context)
```

urls.py (as requested by commenter):

```
from crewcal.views import user, log_in
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout
from crewcal import models, views
from crewcal.forms import CustomRegistrationForm
# from crewcal.forms import RegistrationFormUniqueEmail


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', 'crewcal.views.index', name='home'),
    # url(r'^ssc/', include('ssc.foo.urls')),

    url(r'^events/(?P<event_id>\d+)/$', 'crewcal.views.event', name='events'),
    url(r'^events/new/$', 'crewcal.views.new_event', name='new_event'),
    url(r'^commit/$', 'crewcal.views.commit', name='commit'),
    url(r'^users/(?P<user_name>[A-Za-z]+)/$', 'crewcal.views.user', name="user-profile"),
    url(r'^users/(?P<user_name>\d+)/$', 'crewcal.views.user', name="user-profile"),

    url(r'^', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),

    url(r'^register/$', 'RegistrationView',
    {'form_class':CustomRegistrationForm,
        'backend':'registration.backends.default.DefaultBackend' }, name='registration_register'),
#   For Registration simple, one-step login
#    url(r'^', include('registration.backends.simple.urls')),

     url(r'^facebook/', include('django_facebook.urls')),
    # (r'^$', include('django_facebook.auth_urls')),


    url(r'^messages/', include('postman.urls')),


    # url(r'^event/$', views.object_list, {'model': models.Event}),

    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.urls')),

    # url(r'^register/$', register, name='join'),
    url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', logout, {'next_page': '/'}, name='logout'),
    url(r'^log_in/$', log_in, name='log_in'),
```

Here's the form rendered in the page:

```
<p>
<form action="/commit/" method="post" id="event-commit">
<input type="hidden" name="event_id" id="event_id" value="4">
<input type="submit" value="Commit to this event &raquo;" class="btn")">
<div style='display:none'><input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='XXOqtkkxYQ0zAN1sv3KYxVD8ljhjMpit' /></div>
</form>
</p>
```

But the consequent page breaks because the event_id (or anything else) is present in the POST dictionary:

```
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

...

request 
"<WSGIRequest\npath:/commit/,\nGET:<QueryDict: {}>,\nPOST:<QueryDict: {}>,\nCOOKIES:

...
```

This is happening in my Heroku staging environment but not locally. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Could you please show us the code for your view? Did you use django forms?

Comment: instead of using `render_to_response` use `render`. Its better. Which version of django are you using btw?

Comment: @Games Brainiac – Django 1.4.1

Comment: Okay then. Use `render` its from shortcuts as well. Tell me if things improve.

Comment: I am now using `return render(request, 'event.html', context)` still getting `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''` and an empty POST dict.

Comment: Note that I'm setting the form value in the template and not using forms. The html seems to be rendering the form correctly and POSTing the value which should pass it to the commit view POST dictionary, right? Works locally!

Comment: Then is is might be a bug. Try with django 1.5.1 See if there are any changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm maybe this line caused the error:

```
event_id = request.POST.get('event_id','')
event = Event.objects.get(pk=event_id)
```

You need to pass `int` instead of `string` to pk, so change it to something like:

```
event_id = request.POST.get('event_id', 0)
event = Event.objects.get(pk=int(event_id))
```

**EDIT:**

You also have this part of code:

```
except GraphAPI.OAuthError, e:
    print e.message
    return redirect('commit')
```

So if there is an exception, it's automatically redirect to this same view with an empty querydict. I think that could be the source of the problem, could you remove that redirection and try again?

Comment: That doesn't work, I tried it in staging just to be sure. The problem seems to be an empty POST field. So when I change the variable type `event_id` becomes `0`, so error is event DoesNotExist. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: Hmm could you post your urls.py?

Comment: Sure. It's in there now.

Comment: Thanks, just curious, how did you get that debug info of request? by `print request` in `commit()` view?

Comment: I set debug to True so this shows in the standard Django error page output. I also have Sentry running and use debug-toolbar to get different perspectives.

Comment: I noticed one more problem, could you check my edited answer?

Comment: Thank you so much. You got it. Will have to deal with that Facebook error. I appreciate your assistance very much.